# Android coroutines "Possibly blocking call in non-blocking context could lead to thread starvation"

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have code like this:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    binding.titleIcon.setImageBitmap(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                            URL(titleIcon.formatImageUrl())
                                .openConnection()
                                .getInputStream()
                        )
                    )
            }
```

This code gets me warning from the question title on the both lines:

```
.openConnection()
 .getInputStream()
```

I don't understand why, My code is executed on background thread, Main thread should be fine, why is this message written. Even though this code works and does not crash, I don't like warnings in code and want to understand what is going on here.

It suggests me wrapping with withContext. So when I change this code to:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        binding.titleIcon.setImageBitmap(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                                URL(titleIcon.formatImageUrl())
                                    .openConnection()
                                    .getInputStream()
                            )
                        )
                }
}
```

warnings dissapear and everything seems fine. Can anyone give nice explanation about this?

Comment: Lint might be confused by your creation of a (leaked) `CoroutineScope`. Consider using an appropriate [lifecycle scope for your activity or fragment](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines). Also consider moving your network I/O to a viewmodel (and use `viewModelScope`) rather than doing I/O directly in an activity or fragment. Finally, updating UI in a background thread is risky; prefer to call `setImageBitmap()` on the main application thread.

Comment: In other words: this should be safe, the linter is wrong and you can suppress the warning. However, your code contains other problems and they could cause the linter to generate a false positive.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I call setImageBitmap() on main thread, I change with withcontext(Disaptchers.Main). This is just sample code to show the problem. Yes I always do I/O in viewmodel, but this custom view has only this line of code that needs to be executed in background so I think creating Viewmodel only for this small code is not needed

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes before asking question I tried also with lifecycleScope.launch instead of CoroutineScope, but I get same warnings :/
(This is not fragment/activity, but this is custom view). I override function  override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
        return (context as LifecycleOwner).lifecycle
    }.  to use lifecycleScope, but it did not help...

Comment: @broot yes I understand. Funny part is that all the things Commons said I always follow. This is just situation where I wanted code in question to be smaller so people could get easier to the problematic part. But you are right, I should do better explanation and not write code that is not optimal in questions. Lesson learned! :D

Comment: "I tried also with lifecycleScope.launch instead of CoroutineScope, but I get same warnings" -- you should still use a suitable lifecycle scope. "This is not fragment/activity, but this is custom view" -- doing I/O from within the code of a custom view is a significant code smell. It will also hamper your ability to write instrumented tests for this custom view, as those tests would need to do network I/O.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok so creating viewmodel is must I guess. Can we than conclude that whenever we have any background work (even very small like this one) in fragment/activity/custom_view we should always use viewmodel. I mean We create new viewmodel class, we inject it with DI, we observe flow variable inside it, we write more code in this scenario. I thought moving this from viewmodel in this situation was saving resorces... I understand downside but I thought I get upper hand with these things I wrote up.

Comment: "Ok so creating viewmodel is must I guess" -- personally, for a custom view, I would have a method on the view to accept the `Bitmap`. How that `Bitmap` is obtained is not the custom view's responsibility. And then you might already have a suitable viewmodel for your activity or fragment that is using the custom view. "we should always use viewmodel" -- if you are doing the I/O yourself, IMHO, yes. There are existing image loading libraries like Glide and Coil that I would use.